# Remove space between button - datepicker

Tags: css, angular

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-io-datepicker to provide a datepicker in an Angular 4 form.

Date picker selecter is used such as

```
<date-picker format="Y-MM-DD" [showClearButton]="true" formControlName="date1" ></date-picker>
```

This renders a UI as

[image: Calendar]

I want to get rid of the space between the input field, the 'X' button and the calendar.

Upon inspecting in developer tools, it seems this space is coming as a result of margin-left being set to 10px. This is how the CSS looks like in developer tools

```
.datepicker-actions__button[_ngcontent-c5] {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 .77rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: .25em;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Now, I need to override the CSS to change margin-left to 0px.

I tried applying a inline style to the

```
<date-picker format="Y-MM-DD" [showClearButton]="true" formControlName="date1" style="margin-left: 0;"></date-picker>
```

Then I tried to override the CSS by creating the below CSS in Angular 4 component CSS, but this didn't work as well

```
.datepicker-actions__button {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

button[class^="datepicker-actions"], button[class*=" datepicker-actions"] {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

What can I do to change the margin-left property set as a part of the Datepicker component?

Comment: Try using ``/deep/``. CSS of components in Angular is usually encapsulated, but you can use ``/deep/`` selector in CSS to "break" that encapsulation for a specific purpose.

Comment: Do you mean something like /deep/ .datepicker-actions__button {...}
My IDE complains when I do that.

Comment: It is possible your IDE does not understand it. Does not make it wrong. But it is possible you are not using it correctly. Although what you sent in your comment seems ok.